# Como manter a apresentação dos dados do modal

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Desenvolvi uma tela que apresenta os benefícios concedidos ao cidadão, sistema voltado para assistência social, segue a view :

```
<!--onblur ="validaNomeCidadaoGeral('dcbe_usu_codigo','dcbe_usu_nome','dcbealert_usu_nome')" -->
<div class="conteudo" >
    <legend>Itens benefício eventual</legend>
    <p class="msgAviso" id="beneficios-msg" <?=(count($this->dadosBenItens)>0 ? "style='display: none;'" : "style='display: show;'")?>>
    </p>
    <div class="msgAviso" id="dcbealert_exc_bei" style="display: none;"></div>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="beneficios_inseridos" 
        <?=(count($this->dadosBenItens)>0 ? "style='display: show;'" : "style='display: none;'")?>>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Benefício</th>
            <th>Tipo de benefício</th>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Benefício concedido</th>
            <th>Data Prevista</th>
            <th>Data Entrega</th>
            <th>Finaliza Entrega</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        if (count($this->dadosBenItens)>0) {
        // die('sdsadas')
        foreach($this->dadosBenItens as $ite) { ?>
            <tr id='beneficio_inserido<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>'>

                <td class="center">
                    <?=$ite->beneficio?>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    Tipo de benefício
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <?=$ite->asbdi_qtd?>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <?=$ite->asbdi_valor?>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <?=($ite->asbdi_concedido == 1 ? 'Sim' : 'Não')?>
                </td>

                <td class="center">
                    <?=($ite->asbdi_data_entrega)?>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <p id = "" style="display: none"><?=($ite->asbdi_entrega)?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <button onclick="gerarDataEntrega(<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>)">Finliza Entrega</button>
                    </div>
                </td> 
            </tr>

        <?php }
            } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Resultado : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo certo eu clico no botão ele carregar as funções necessárias , salva a data da entrega do benefício e boa. Após o success do ajax eu gostaria de esconder o botão e apresentar a data .

```
function gerarDataEntrega (id){
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + "/atendimentocras/beneficios-cidadao/data-entrega/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id },
        success: function(resultado){

        }
    });
}
```

Mais o problema é que tudo esta em um foreach dificultando a apresentação da data de entrega caso o cidadão possua mais de um benefício . E outra como eu posso manter essa apresentação fixa ? .

Comment: Um usar o próprio modal seria a solução mais fácil ?

Comment: Eu estava usando o resultado com um console.log só para verificar se estava chegando a resposta, ter algum feed no processo só isso.

Comment: Não, eu clico no botão e não acontece a alteração , preciso fechar e abrir o modal.

Comment: Então. Vc disse na resposta abaixo que quando vc fecha a modal e abre novamente, o botão volta a aparecer. Então me parece que essa lista que aparece na modal é carregada de forma dinâmica, senão o botão não voltaria a aparecer, certo?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar o `id` no botão, e no success do AJAX você manipula ele com jQuery.

```
<div>
   <button id="id-botao-<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>"
           onclick="gerarDataEntrega(<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>)">
      Finliza Entrega
   </button>
</div>

success: function(resultado){
     $('#id-botao-'+id).hide();
     // faz o que precisa com a sua variável 'resultado' 
     ...
}
```

É isso que você quer fazer?

Comment: Quase isso ele funciona corretamente porém, fechou o e abriu o modal ele volta a ficar visível  . Eu manter ele invisível entende .Tipo gerou a data entrega sumiu não aparece mais. Não sei se é possível também.

Comment: Outra coisa também, eu clico no botão a data da entrega não carrega eu tenho fechar o modal ai sim ela esta visível. Parece que processa tudo porém é necessário um reload. Ai acontece a atualização na view.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algumas alterações no código , validando se o cidadão já possui benefícios .Caso ele já possua o botão de gerar data não é apresentado. Como ficou :

```
<!--onblur ="validaNomeCidadaoGeral('dcbe_usu_codigo','dcbe_usu_nome','dcbealert_usu_nome')" -->
<div class="conteudo" >
    <legend>Itens benefício eventual</legend>
    <p class="msgAviso" id="beneficios-msg" <?=(count($this->dadosBenItens)>0 ? "style='display: none;'" : "style='display: show;'")?>>
    </p>
    <div class="msgAviso" id="dcbealert_exc_bei" style="display: none;"></div>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="beneficios_inseridos" 
        <?=(count($this->dadosBenItens)>0 ? "style='display: show;'" : "style='display: none;'")?>>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Benefício</th>
                <th>Tipo de benefício</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Benefício concedido</th>
                <th>Data Prevista</th>
                <th>Data Entrega</th>
                <th>Finaliza Entrega</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        if (count($this->dadosBenItens)>0) {
        // die('sdsadas')
        foreach($this->dadosBenItens as $ite) { ?>

                    <tr id='beneficio_inserido<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>'>

                        <td class="center">
                            <?=$ite->beneficio?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            Tipo de benefício
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <?=$ite->asbdi_qtd?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <?=$ite->asbdi_valor?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <?=($ite->asbdi_concedido == 1 ? 'Sim' : 'Não')?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="center">
                            <?=($ite->asbdi_data_entrega)?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <p id="" style=""><?=($ite->asbdi_entrega)?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
            <?php if ($ite->asbdi_entrega == null): ?>
                            <div>
                                <button id="id-botao-<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>"
                                       onclick="gerarDataEntrega(<?=$ite->asbdi_codigo?>)">
                                  Finaliza Entrega
                                </button>
                            </div>
            <?php endif ?>
                        </td> 

                    </tr>
        <?php }
            } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Fiz uma pequena alteração no ajax :

```
function gerarDataEntrega (id){
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + "/atendimentocras/beneficios-cidadao/data-entrega/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id },
        success: function(resultado){
            alert("Data de entrega efetuada com sucesso.");
            location.reload()
        }
    });
}
```

Essa foi a forma que eu achei para resolver este problema , claro que as ideias do tópico me ajudaram e muito na conclusão.